# file chooser dialog issue on Marshmallow in android

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

I have try to open a dialog that can open a dialog for file chooser for creating folders it have working fine upto kitkat bt in Marshmallow it can't show internal or external memory card storage i have also set permission on runtime but i am not able to show open internal storage or external memory card. Anyone face same problem please help me?  I have also pasted my code below. Thanks in advance

```
public class DirectoryChooserDialog {

private boolean m_isNewFolderEnabled = true;
private String m_sdcardDirectory = "";
private Context m_context;
private TextView m_titleView;

private String m_dir = "";
private List<String> m_subdirs = null;
private ChosenDirectoryListener m_chosenDirectoryListener = null;
private ArrayAdapter<String> m_listAdapter = null;
private ImageView ivBack;

// ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Callback interface for selected directory
// ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public interface ChosenDirectoryListener {
    public void onChosenDir(String chosenDir);
}

public DirectoryChooserDialog(Context context,
        ChosenDirectoryListener chosenDirectoryListener) {
    m_context = context;
    File test = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    m_sdcardDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath();
    m_chosenDirectoryListener = chosenDirectoryListener;

    try {
        m_sdcardDirectory = new File(m_sdcardDirectory).getCanonicalPath();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
    }
}

// /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// setNewFolderEnabled() - enable/disable new folder button
// /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public void setNewFolderEnabled(boolean isNewFolderEnabled) {
    m_isNewFolderEnabled = isNewFolderEnabled;
}

public boolean getNewFolderEnabled() {
    return m_isNewFolderEnabled;
}

// /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// chooseDirectory() - load directory chooser dialog for initial
// default sdcard directory


public void chooseDirectory() {
    // Initial directory is sdcard directory
    chooseDirectory(m_sdcardDirectory);
}

// //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// chooseDirectory(String dir) - load directory chooser dialog for initial
// input 'dir' directory
// //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public void chooseDirectory(String dir) {
    File dirFile = new File(dir);
    if (!dirFile.exists() || !dirFile.isDirectory()) {
        dir = m_sdcardDirectory;
    }

    try {
        dir = new File(dir).getCanonicalPath();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        return;
    }

    m_dir = dir;
    m_subdirs = getDirectories(dir);

    class DirectoryOnClickListener implements
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            // Navigate into the sub-directory
            m_dir += "/"
                    + ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView().getAdapter()
                            .getItem(item);
            updateDirectory();
        }
    }

    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = createDirectoryChooserDialog(dir,
            m_subdirs, new DirectoryOnClickListener());

    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Current directory chosen
            if (m_chosenDirectoryListener != null) {
                // Call registered listener supplied with the chosen
                // directory
                m_chosenDirectoryListener.onChosenDir(m_dir);
            }
        }
    }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);

    final AlertDialog dirsDialog = dialogBuilder.create();

    dirsDialog.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode,
                KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
                    && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                // Back button pressed
                if (m_dir.equals(m_sdcardDirectory)) {
                    // The very top level directory, do nothing
                    return false;
                } else {
                    // Navigate back to an upper directory
                    m_dir = new File(m_dir).getParent();
                    updateDirectory();
                }

                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });

    // Show directory chooser dialog
    dirsDialog.show();
}

private boolean createSubDir(String newDir) {
    File newDirFile = new File(newDir);
    if (!newDirFile.exists()) {
        return newDirFile.mkdir();
    }

    return false;
}

private List<String> getDirectories(String dir) {
    List<String> dirs = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        File dirFile = new File(dir);
        if (!dirFile.exists() || !dirFile.isDirectory()) {
            return dirs;
        }

        for (File file : dirFile.listFiles()) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                dirs.add(file.getName());
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    Collections.sort(dirs, new Comparator<String>() {
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        }
    });

    return dirs;
}

private AlertDialog.Builder createDirectoryChooserDialog(String title,
        List<String> listItems,
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener onClickListener) {
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(m_context);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) m_context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View convertView = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.layout_header_filechooser_dialog, null);
    // Create custom view for AlertDialog title containing
    // current directory TextView and possible 'New folder' button.
    // Current directory TextView allows long directory path to be wrapped
    // to multiple lines.
    LinearLayout titleLayout = new LinearLayout(m_context);
    titleLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    titleLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00ff00"));

    // m_titleView = new TextView(m_context);
    m_titleView = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.tv_title_dialog_file_chooser);
    // m_titleView.setLayoutParams(new
    // LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    // LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    // m_titleView.setTextAppearance(m_context,
    // android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
    // m_titleView.setTextColor(m_context.getResources().getColor(
    // android.R.color.white));
    // m_titleView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL
    // | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    m_titleView.setText(title);

    // Button newDirButton = new Button(m_context);
    Button newDirButton = (Button) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.btn_create_new_folder_dialog_file_chooser);
    ivBack = (ImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.iv_back_dialog_file_chooser);
    if (m_dir.equals(m_sdcardDirectory)) {
        ivBack.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        ivBack.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    ivBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (m_dir.equals(m_sdcardDirectory)) {
                // The very top level directory, do nothing
            } else {
                // Navigate back to an upper directory
                m_dir = new File(m_dir).getParent();
                updateDirectory();
            }
        }
    });
    // newDirButton.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
    // LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    // newDirButton.setText("Click For New folder");
    // newDirButton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    // newDirButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#197319"));
    newDirButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final EditText input = new EditText(m_context);

            // Show new folder name input dialog
            new AlertDialog.Builder(m_context)
                    .setTitle("New folder name")
                    .setView(input)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int whichButton) {
                                    Editable newDir = input.getText();
                                    String newDirName = newDir.toString();
                                    // Create new directory
                                    if (createSubDir(m_dir + "/"
                                            + newDirName)) {
                                        // Navigate into the new directory
                                        m_dir += "/" + newDirName;
                                        updateDirectory();
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(
                                                m_context,
                                                "Failed to create '"
                                                        + newDirName
                                                        + "' folder",
                                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", null).show();
        }
    });

    if (!m_isNewFolderEnabled) {
        newDirButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    // titleLayout.addView(m_titleView);
    // titleLayout.addView(newDirButton);

    dialogBuilder.setCustomTitle(convertView);

    m_listAdapter = createListAdapter(listItems);

    dialogBuilder.setSingleChoiceItems(m_listAdapter, -1, onClickListener);
    dialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);

    return dialogBuilder;
}

private void updateDirectory() {
    m_subdirs.clear();
    m_subdirs.addAll(getDirectories(m_dir));
    m_titleView.setText(m_dir);
    if (m_dir.equals(m_sdcardDirectory)) {
        ivBack.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        ivBack.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    m_listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private ArrayAdapter<String> createListAdapter(List<String> items) {
    return new ArrayAdapter<String>(m_context,
            android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, android.R.id.text1, items) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            if (v instanceof TextView) {
                // Enable list item (directory) text wrapping
                TextView tv = (TextView) v;
                tv.getLayoutParams().height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                tv.setEllipsize(null);
            }
            return v;
        }
    };
  }

}
```

Comment: whats ur targetSdk?

Comment: you have to ask run-time permission for 6.0?

Comment: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11"
              android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

Comment: when i use 23 tagetsdk, app is crash please give me solution when i use file explorer in marshmellow device the external storage (sd card) file does not show. on that time i use targetsdk 19.

Comment: @Maa iOSBefore reading storage ask permission at runtime otherwise it will not work?

Comment: have look on this ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37429857/android-6-error-in-reading-device-id-to-give-permission-in-my-code/37430911#37430911

Comment: i have already set permission  on my code

Comment: @Mss iOS solved your issue yet?

Comment: not yet done thats why i post on stackoverflow

Comment: @MssiOS can you show us your run time permission code ?

Comment: i have also set max sdk version 19  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11"
              android:targetSdkVersion="19" /> bt exrenal storage can,t show on marsmallow devices now i have remove my runtime permisson